How to set max_memory pool of pyarrow to just use max available on the instance?
I've a machine with 80GB RAM but whenever it does the pa.concat_tables operation, it goes out of memory.
I've tried doing the following to set the default memory pool but it's showing the total_allocated_bytes as 0:
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> pa.set_memory_pool(pa.system_memory_pool())
>>> pa.total_allocated_bytes()
0

How to set max_memory pool of pyarrow to just use max available on the instance?

I've also tried this and it seems to work and pa.total_allocated_bytes() is no longer zero but the docs are unclear
import pyarrow as pa
pa.allocate_buffer(1024 * 1024 * 80, resizable=False) # Does this mean 80GB? 


elaborate, share https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of your code that is causing the issue. (how big are these tables...),  have you tried chunking the data then concatenating ?.... until you provide sample code we're guessing  ...

The same code above to set memory is the key part and the main question of how to set max_memory pool for pyarrow. The reason for setting the max memory pool is can be anything but in my case, because the concat_tables are too big. Unfortunately, there's nothing I can do to change the data and even look into it. Only thing I could control is to constrain the memory buffer of PyArrow. According to the doc, it's possible but I'm just not calling/getting the functions right.

Docs referring to https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.allocate_buffer.html#pyarrow.allocate_buffer and https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.set_memory_pool.html

PyArrow by default can use all of the memory on your machine. What's likely going on is that PyArrow is using enough of your machine's memory that the OOM killer is being triggered which kills the process. concat_tables can work in a zero-copy way but isn't able to in your case due to differing schemas on your tables. Posting a reproducible example showing table creation and your call to concat_tables would be the best way to get help.

Any way to just restrict the buffer used by pyarrow without regards for the data? Unfortunately no one can see the data, not even me, so if there's some way to just cap the buffer max memory would be good

pa.allocate_buffer(1024 * 1024 * 80, resizable=False) is around 80meg , pa.show_info() gives some further detail. I don't think you are able to achieve what you are after and not sharing code is not helping anyone help you really. I suggest again that you look into chunking etc

Thank! I think chunking is the root of the issue, I had chunked them up and preprocessed the data to produce N no. of tables and then put the N no. of tables together through pa.concat_tables. Perhaps I should just avoid the initial chunking and preprocess in one single table =)

@alvas, let us know how you get on then , good luck !

Did a quick check, I still can't see what's inside the data but the size of each table that is passed into pa.concat_tables is 100+GB each -_-
